# How does findAssocs() to calculate the correlation value?

Tags: r, correlation, tm

I'm very interested in the math behind the `"tm`" package `findAssocs()` function.
I have found that someone had asked the same question before, and have a good explanation by Rick.
http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/findAssocs-td3845751.html

But I still don't understand how to calculate the correlation value between the two vectors.

For example:

```
# Correlation word2 with word3
cor(c(0,1,1,1,1),c(0,0,1,1,1))     
[1] 0.6123724
```

How does it calculate  `cor(c(0,1,1,1,1),c(0,0,1,1,1))` to get `0.6123724` ?

I have tried use cosine similarly to calculate, but it's not correct. So could anyone guide me to understand this questions??

Comment: That's a Pearson correlation from base R. It has nothing to do with `tm`. See the `?cor` help page.

Comment: thanks I have found the information at this document https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Verzani-SimpleR.pdf